# Azure Repos restrict push to branch from all branches except one

Tags: azure, azure-repos

Imagine, we have branch policy on **Story** branch and it is impossible to push to this branch without completed PR.

But is it possible to allow push to **Story** branch only if name of the branch is **Dev**.

So I need to restrict pushing for all branches except one with particular name

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but I think the answer is no. The server doesn't care about the name of the branch you push from, it only cares what branch you try to push to is, and that's either protected or it's not. However (at least on GitHub, I don't know about Azure Repos), you can give a particular user (typically the repo administrators) permission to push without a PR.

Comment: Note that Git itself has no mechanism for this at all; each hosting system that adds one, adds it in its own way.